# How to stay DRY using private methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, dry, private-methods

I'm on Rails 5.0.
Creating new controllers and adding more and more code there I've discovered that I have quite a lot of identical methods in private sections of each class like

```
private

def find_post
  @post = Posts.find(params[:id])
end

def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def find_group
  ...
end
```

and so on.

Is there any way to include a "standard" set of private methods to all the classes that need it?

Comment: If you think you are using all these methods with actions you can just move the code in one method

Comment: OK, in some cases it makes sense but still it repeats in many classes.

Comment: @AlexanderGorg If you want to dry the controller code, and this methods are also useful in other controller, you can create helper and you can include that helper in your controller.

Comment: @ashvin Even private methods?

Comment: @AlexanderGorg for that you have to create `concerns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) in controllers just like you can in models.

Just define a concern called `Finders` or something in `app/controllers/concerns/finders.rb` and then `include Finders` to use it.

Also note that since Ruby 2.0 `def` actually returns a symbol with the method name, so it is possible to do something like the following:

```
private def find_post
  @post = Posts.find(params[:id])
end

private def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

While it's true that this leads to slightly more typing, it's more explicit and much less error prone than the class level access modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just inherit from a parent controller, using protected methods instead?

```
class PostParentController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user # might be a different method name in Rails 5
  before_filter :find_post

  protected
  def find_post
    @post = Posts.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Subclass:

```
class PostChildController < PostParentController
  def show
  end

  def create
  end

  # etc
end
```

[Ruby public, private, protected methods](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_access_control.html)

Comment: In some cases - that's a decision, but I have voids with very different functionality(image, video, post, etc.), however methods for finding users, votes, answers, etc. are quite the same. I knew that I need some kind of module, but now I definitely know that I needed concerns!